# Auth approach based on dyndns-host on Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, dyndns

I'm searching for an approach permitting access on an apache web server, but only for clients that have an IP address which machtes on an IP address that is assigned to a dynamic host address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly (you want something like `Allow from somehost.dyndns.org`) then no, this is not possible.
Apache gets the request from the IP and does a *reverse* DNS lookup, this will not match and the client will be denied.

The only solution I could think of would be to write a cronjob which periodically resolves the dyndns record and writes an `.htaccess` file allowing only that IP.
But that is rather hackish and I would much rather simply implement authentication instead.